# Vagrant multi-machine with docker tries to create two boot2docker vms

Tags: macos, vagrant, docker

I wanted to set up a small environment consisting of two Docker containers. I prepared Dockerfiles for them and using Docker itself, they spin up correctly. However when I want to use Vagrant on OSX, vagrant up creates two VMs, running into port conflicts and causing one of the Docker containers to not be created at all.

Here is the Vagrantfile I use:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "ldap" do |ldap|
    ldap.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir="ldap"
      d.name="ldap"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "phpldapadmin" do |pla|
    pla.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir="phpldapadmin"
      d.link("ldap:ldap")
      d.ports << "50000:80"
    end
  end
end
```

When I name the containers "phpldapadmin1" and "ldap1" it suddenly works. I tried deleting the .vagrant and my ~/.vagrant.d directories with no luck. Can anyone point me to what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

"vagrant up" tries to "up" all of the apps in parallel, so each will check if the VM is running (it isn't yet) and so each will try to create the VM. Instead, you have to start up the first container in serial, then the rest can be parallel. I have a script called start.sh that basically does this:

```
#/bin/bash

vagrant up an-app # this will start the VM
vagrant up other-app1 other-app2 other-app3 # these can startup in parallel since the VM exists
```

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the next release, see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3963